# Vertical align floated image + container (H+p)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to center an floated image and a container (paragraph + heading):

```css
.row {
  display: block;
  /* width: 100%; */
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="right" src="" width="300" height="300" />
    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="left" src="" width="300" height="156" />
    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is also a [live version of the problem](http://dev.dashbox.si/kaj-je-dashbox). I have cleared the floats but now I can't center the .img and .container element. What would you slove the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no luck with floated elements since they don't obey vertical-align. You can instead use `display: table-cell` along with `vertical-align: middle` and that would work perfectly. Albeit you will need to modify your HTML structure a little bit to place the content first before the image and vice versa depending on the way you want the content and images to appear on the front-end.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}
.content {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dev.dashbox.si/media/wysiwyg/vsebina-dashboxa.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dev.dashbox.si/media/wysiwyg/vsebina-dashboxa.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Do you recommend me an source or e-book to start learning CSS the right way?

Comment: @PeterPupovac As a beginner, you can learn basic CSS using the W3schools CSS guide here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp. It's quite good and contains a long list of CSS properties to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you can do to vertically align text is change the display of the container to table then the paragraph to table-cell and then set the vertical-align to middle looking like this:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left, .right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You might also need to set overflow to hidden on the container so that the height is maintained because of the floats.